# Vertical-align on a Bootstrap column in a height-defined container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a vertical-align on **col-sm-12** inside of a **height-defined container** but this doesn't work.

I have tried a lot of different methods and nothing seems to work.

```css
.home-main-elem {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('XXXX') no-repeat bottom left;
    height: 450px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #FFF;
}
h1 {color: #FFF;}
.font-orange {color: #ffcc43;}
.vertical-middle {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="home-main-elem">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 vertical-middle">
                <h1>Welcome to <span class="font-orange">XXXX</span></h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum qui dolore quam et fugiat hic tenetur, quasi in doloremque reiciendis quia, blanditiis eaque adipisci explicabo, facere enim fuga repellendus sunt!
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-orange">SIGN UP</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have ypu try this : <div class="col-sm-12" align='center'>

Comment: Do you mean you want a column that's two rows high, while the other ones are one row high?

Comment: can you please add your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Bootstrap framework does not have a great way 'Out of the box' of vertically centering the content.

There are 2 ways I can think of how to do this but it would require additional CSS and HTML.

Method 1: Use `display: flex`

[See an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/hqLoxd50/2/)

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The CSS flexbox model allows us to better manage how our elements are positioned.

Method 2: Use `display: table`

[See an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/hqLoxd50/1/)

```
.wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Table cells are capable of being vertically centered within a table

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these styles to the elements:

```
.home-main-elem {
    position: relative;
}

.vertical-middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

Comment: The alignement works but the only negative side i've found is the face that now the text on the <p></p> does not respect the width anymore

Comment: What do you mean with that exactly? When I'm testing your code in my browser, the text behaves exactly the same as without my changes.

Comment: The <p></p> content goes all the way to the right, ignoring the <div class="container"></div> size